# apt-get update - trying to install python OpenCV on rasp pi?

Tags: raspbian, python-3, opencv

```
$ apt-get update

Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

I am not sure what does is and not have idea how solve it as i am trying to install openCV on my pi to use camera for Deep learning..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't run this command by `root` user. Therefore, this user doesn't have any access to update the repository list.
Try these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Or, run it directly as `root` user:

```
su
```

Then, fire `apt-get update`.